# Order of an element as a product

Tags: group-theory

I apologise if this has been asked before, but I wasn't able to find it..

I am trying to prove that if $g\in G$, where $G$ is an arbitrary group,$|g| = n$, where $n = ab$, with $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, then there exist $h,k\in G$ such that $g = hk$, and $|h| = a$, $|k| = b$.

So far I have reasoned that the identity and $g$ itself would be suitable choices for $h$ and $k$. 
However, I am asked to determine if there are more than one choice for $h$ and $k$.

It seems to me that if $G$ is cyclic, then there might me more than one choice for $h,k$ as in finite abelian groups, the product of two elements have order equal to the product of their order. But I am wondering if they would satisfy the $\gcd(a,b)=1$ criteria, and what happens when $G$ is not cyclic?

I hope someone might be able to help me out!

Comment: Your argument that $g$ and the identity are suitable choices is wrong in general. It is only valid when $|g|$ is prime.

Comment: I think you should require $\;a,b\neq 1\;$ , otherwise you always have the trivial choice $\;a=g\;,\;b=1\;$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $ gcd(a, b) = 1$ there are such $c,d$ that $ac+bd=1$. Set $h=g^{bd}, k=g^{ac}$.

The choice is unique. If we have another such pair $h_1,k_1$ then  $hk=h_1k_1$ implies  $h^{-1}h_1=k^{-1}k_1$. Denote this element by $x$, then $x^a=(h^{-1}h_1)^a=1$ and simlarly $x^b=1$. Again from  $ac+bd=1$ it follows $x=1$ etc.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Does that mean that h and k are not unique, as there might be more than one solution ac+bd=1?

Comment: @groupgeek I am adding the answer.

Comment: How do we prove that $|h|=a$ and $|k|=b$? It's obvious that $h^a=e$ and $k^b=e$, but how can I verify that those are the smallest possible degrees for which that holds?

Comment: I think I've answered my own question, but the argument is possibly less trivial than it should be. I'd appreciate a simple solution if you can come up with one off the top of your head. Let $|k|=x_{1}, |h|=x_{2}$.  Then $$ (g^{ca})^{x_{1}}=e \implies ab|cax_{1} \implies b|cx_{1} \implies b|x_{1}.$$ The second implication is due to $gcd(a, b)=1$ and the third one is due to $gcd(b, c)=1$, which is true because there exist $a, d$ such that $db+ac=1$. $x_{1}|b$ is obvious due to my previous comment, therefore $x_{1}=b$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $g^{ab} = 1$ and gcd$(a,b) = 1$ we know $g^a$ is an element of order $b$. (Prove it!) Can $g^a$ equal $g$ or $1$?

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! I just proved it. But does that also mean that the choice for h and k is unique? I cant't really see if that follows...

Comment: I accidentally missed the part $g = hk$, hence my hint is not very useful. Use the answer above.